# Is SVG elliptical arc curve path command overdetermined?

Tags: path, svg, command, ellipse, geometric-arc

SVG's elliptical arc curve path command takes 9 parameters: implicit current X and Y, `rx` (x-radius), `ry` (y-radius), `x-axis-rotation`, `large-arc-flag`, `sweep-flag`, `x` (endpoint-x), `y` (endpoint-y). Lets ignore the two "flag" parameters that I believe to be unimportant for my question. Then 7 parameters remain.

Now my question is: is the ellipse overdetermined or not? I just believe that it is, because providing too small `rx` and `ry` and an endpoint which is too far the the current point will result in no solution. Thinking this way, only a subset of parameter space forms valid arches, hence the ellipse is overdetermined.

On the other hand, I'm not a geometry expert and I know that SVG is a well-thought-out standard, suggesting that I am wrong. Am I or not?

Comment: I was wrong and now I see why. ``rx`` and ``ry`` parameters are actually not absolute, but relative, they determine ratio. Sadly, I am unable to find this in the standard.

Comment: The standards are very difficult to follow

Comment: It might say somewhere that where parameters are inconsistent that defauts are used to override..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/implnote.html#ArcOutOfRangeParameters

> If rx, ry and φ are such that there is no solution (basically, the ellipse is not big enough to reach from (x1, y1) to (x2, y2)) then the ellipse is scaled up uniformly until there is exactly one solution (until the ellipse is just big enough).

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much, I should learn to read better.